# DirectX First Person Camera

Tags: camera, directx, frame-rate

Im using the directx sample meshFromOBJ10, i have replaced the microsfot obj file with a mesh of a gun.

i want the camera positioned so that when it starts the camera is just behind the gun, much like in a FPS game however i dont know how to do this, im relatively new to directX and could do with a little help

```
// Setup the camera's view parameters
D3DXVECTOR3 vecEye( 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
D3DXVECTOR3 vecAt ( 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.0f );
g_Camera.SetViewParams( &vecEye, &vecAt );
```

this is how its set by default but i need it changed and dont know how any help would be appreciated thanks. nothing else has been changed in the code so far so it can be found just by looking at the directx sample i previously mentioned

Answer (score 0):

[D3DXMatrixLookAtLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)